# Is it correct to use the word "devastated" to refer to the pain we feel towards other people?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I think the word *devastated* is mainly used when something bad happens to oneself (maybe I'm wrong?) Say, can I use it in the following way?

> I felt **devastated** after watching the survivors of Hurricane Katrina.

If not, what's a better option?

Comment: One could be 'devastated' at *anyone's* misfortune, if one does really feel so. *devastated* syn. shattered, shocked, stunned, overcome, crushed, overwhelmed, distressed, gutted (slang), dazed, knocked sideways (informal), knocked for six http://www.thefreedictionary.com/devastated

Comment: I was devastated when Princess Diana died in a criminally-induced accident, regardless that my Kevin Bacon degrees with Princess Diana was tens of thousands apart.

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't be able to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is perfectly grammatical, and perfectly common to boot. The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) has a number of cites, including these ones:

*

> Just before Christmas, two years after Mara's death, I became distraught one afternoon after a visit from a woman I had considered a friend. **I suddenly felt devastated** by Mara's death, the betrayal of a friend. **The pain was deep and extreme. I was overwhelmed by it. I felt desperate. I had never felt pain so intense. I had no idea what to do.** I went out into the snow for a walk.

- 

> The son also implied that my friend had not retired and moved to warmer climes, but that he had ended his own life, very quietly, and left no note of explanation. **I felt devastated, bereft, empty, on the point of real tears**, but almost as quickly I wondered what had happened to the books he so carefully annotated, his archive, for he was a great collector and recorder of oddities.

- 

> **I felt devastated.** I felt like no one would listen to me. I felt like a very wicked person. **I felt hollow and numb, and I just didn't know what to do.**

- 

> **I felt devastated.** I didn't confront her or stand up for myself. **I just felt awful.**

As you can see, these also conveniently offer a number of other phrases you could use (emphasis added).